# Documentation description shows as "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers"

Tags: bug, documentation, description

When I pasted the link to [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) in a Slack message, the thumbnail Slack displayed included the description "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" which it must be picking up from the meta tag or the Javascript on the page.

The description should be distinct as laid out on the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation).

Comment: Could that be because what we call "Documentation" is basically a subdirectory of stackoverflow.com? Its URL looks like `stackoverflow.com/documentation`.

Comment: I think that's because Documentation looks indistinguishable from Q&A without question words in titles.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Slack docs](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204399343-Sharing-links-in-Slack):

> When you share a link in a Slack message, the link preview contains embedded information from Twitter Cards, oEmbed, or Open Graph.

I think the "embedded information" referred to is the target's `<head>` section, which includes the following in the case of the SO documentation landing page (view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/documentation):

```
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" />
```

I believe this is what the SO team need to fix.